# AddString in List Box (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I am a newbie writing MFC code, and I have a problem adding a string to a list box. The code shown works OK when I call the AddString object directly, but not when I add it to my own Test object as shown. WHat do I have to do so that AddString still works from inside another object? Maybe some kind of inheritance problem?

Thanks for bearing with me on this newbie question!
Duncan

```
void CFileProcessorDlg::Test()
{
    m_strFullName1.Format(_T("Starting to process files"));
    m_Message1.AddString(m_strFullName1); // Add string to list box
}

void CFileProcessorDlg::OnClickedButtonStart()
{
    //Duncan's Stuff
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CFileProcessorDlg dlg;

    UpdateData(); // Transfer data from controls to variables

    //dlg.ProcessFiles(m_InputFile, m_OutputFile); // Actually process the files here

    // Problem 5/22/2017 - this works here, but not if I move it into the Test object.
    //m_strFullName1.Format(_T("Starting to process files"));
    //m_Message1.AddString(m_strFullName1); // Add string to list box
    dlg.Test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminology first: the entity you're calling "my own Test *object*" is actually a *method*.

That out of the way, you're instantiating a(nother) `CFileProcessorDlg` object (named `dlg`) from within your `CFileProcessorDlg::OnCickedButtonStart()` method.

That `dlg` object is created, you call its `Test()` method, and then the object goes out of scope at the end of `CFileProcessorDlg::OnCickedButtonStart()`, so it would not have any useful effect on the object calling object (`this`).

I think you want to do something like this:

```
void CFileProcessorDlg::OnClickedButtonStart()
{
    //Duncan's Stuff
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    UpdateData(); // Transfer data from controls to variables

    //dlg.ProcessFiles(m_InputFile, m_OutputFile); // Actually process the files here

    // Problem 5/22/2017 - this works here, but not if I move it into the Test object.
    //m_strFullName1.Format(_T("Starting to process files"));
    //m_Message1.AddString(m_strFullName1); // Add string to list box
    Test(); // more explicitly: this->Test()
}
```

I left your comments for context, but the net change was to not instantiate a new `CFileProcessorDlg` object.

Comment: It works great, many thanks. I also learned what a method is!